# Change text on a button type when clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't change the text of a button when the button type is button, but I can change it if the type is input

The code for the button is

```
<button type='button'
        id='1'
        name='4'
        class='btn btn-select'>Text I want to change</button>
```

In the handler I am trying to change it like so:

```
document.getElementById("1").value="New Button Text";
```

If I change it input type it works? Why?

Comment: Does it work?  If it does, the button and input type submit may behave ithe same way in this regard.

Comment: Do you mean `<input type="button" value="Text I want to change">` works, but `<button>Text I want to change</button>` does not?  In terms of the  HTML DOM, `.value` is referring to the `value` attribute, not the `innerText` or `nodeValue`.

Comment: In button the text which you see is the innerHTML not the value attribute.
try changing it will innerHTML

Comment: Why was the question down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
document.getElementById("1").innerText="New Button Text";
```

you are use the button as a tag not as input field

Comment: Yes that worked lovely, thankyou, I am sure I tried that but oh well, thanks

Comment: Good luck in your projects.Choose Best answer

Answer (score 0):

The label for a `<input type="button">` is determined by the `value` attribute. An `<input type="submit">` gets its label and submitted data from the `value` attribute (they can't be different).

The label for a `<button>` element is determined by its **text content**. The `value` attribute determines what data it will submit to the server (if it were a **submit** button) when clicked. They can be different.

```js
document.getElementById("1").textContent = "New Button Text";
```

```html
<button type='button' id='1' name='4' class='btn btn-select'>Text I want to change</button>
```

Comment: ? That doesnt do anything?

Comment: @wayneuk2 — When you click "Run code snippet", does the button display "Text I want to change"?